# conditional cookie in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

```
$('nav #mobileMenu').on('click', function() {

    if ($.cookie('isToggled') == 'true')
        var isToggled = $.cookie('isToggled');
    else
        var isToggled = $(this).data('isToggled');

    if ($.cookie('isToggled') == 'true') {
        // this opens the menu
        $(this).parent().addClass("mobileMenuActive");
        $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeIn(1000);
        $(this).parent().find('em').fadeOut('fast');
    } else {
        // this hides the menu
        $(this).parent().removeClass("mobileMenuActive");
        $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeOut(1000);
        $(this).parent().find('em').fadeIn('fast');   
    }

    $(this).data('isToggled', !isToggled)
    $.cookie('isToggled', !isToggled, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
});
```

It works great however when the class is added 'mobileMenuActive' I would like it to set a cookie for a period of 1 day, so when the user goes to another page in the site the menu still has that class, if they click the toggle: 'nav #mobileMenu' once the cookie has been set, the cookie will be removed or set to false, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

I have tried toggling cookies, but the condition doesn't seem to work which I did.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238890/save-div-toggle-state-with-jquery-cookie

Comment: Not really I am saying this bit isn't working:

if ($.cookie('isToggled') === 'true') { and I tried if ($.cookie('isToggled') == true) {, the cookie in firbug console is changing on click but the mobileMenuActive isn't being added.

Comment: In your code you are adding mobileMenuActive class  if ($.cookie_name == 'true') {... shoudnt it be ($.cookie('isToggled') == 'true') or (isToggled =='true')?

Comment: I was trying a variety of things but still no luck, I have updated the question to say if ($.cookie('isToggled') == 'true') { but the class isn't being added and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you checked $(this).parent() to make sure it does not add the class to the wrong element?

Comment: Thanks Calinaadi, It does seem to be adding the class (the class is being added to the right element) but only on the 2nd click, however the cookie is added on the first click and then the class is added on second click which is quite odd as it should add the cookie and add the class on first click, set the cookie value to false, and remove the class on 2nd click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91769/discussion-between-graham-barnes-and-calinaadi).